# How can I calculate the standard deviation of frequencies (signal processing), out of a list of frequencies using python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, audio-processing

`Hello everyone, I'm a student for electrical engineering, I'm new to python and I have an assignment on signal processing course. The assignment was to record myself, preform fft, pass it through a BPF and calculate the mean frequency, and standard deviation of the frequency. Next, I suppose to use the results to isolate the second and third harmonies of my voice. I couldn't find any answer when I looked through the internet.

I recorded myself and preformed fft, passed it into a Butterworth Band Pass Filter, then calculated the mean frequency which gave me a reasonable answer. When I tried to calculate the standard deviation, the result was around 70 times greater than the mean frequency, for any constellation I've tried and it's not making sense. I tried to normalize the magnitude of the file to its maximum value, and also the frequency to its maximum value, I also tried to multiply the frequency (f) with the squared magnitude and divide by the sum of the squared amplitude's list, and also tried to use the np.std() func.
I'm adding my code here and I hope someone can enlighten my eyes, thanks upfront.

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as sig

def mean_freq(data, sample_rate):
    x = fft(data) # List of magnitudes in frequency domain
    f = np.linspace(0.0, sample_rate / 2.0, len(x) // 2)
    abs_x = abs(x)[0:int(len(x) / 2)]
    x_squared = abs_x ** 2
    numerator = sum(f * x_squared)
    denominator = sum(x_squared)
    average_frequency = round(numerator / denominator)
    stdv = np.sqrt((np.sum(f - average_frequency )** 2 ) / len(x)) ### NEED TO CHECK
    return average_frequency, round(stdv)

# Read the soundfile
fs, signal =wav.read('RECORDEDFILE.wav')
# Design characteristics
n = 3 # Filter's order
nyquist = fs/2
t = np.arange(0, 21, 1/fs) # Creating time variable



# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Design BPF of first harmony, BW=70 Hz
lcf = 85/nyquist # Low cut off (Normalized)
hcf = 155/nyquist # High cut off
b, a = sig.butter(n, [lcf , hcf], btype='bandpass', analog=False, output='ba') # Obtain the filter's coefficients

# Activate the filter
filtered_signal = sig.filtfilt(b, a, signal, axis=0)

# First harmony data
mean1, stdv1 = mean_freq(filtered_signal, fs)
print(f'The average frequency of the first harmony is: {mean1} [Hz]')
print(f'The standard deviation of the first harmony is: {stdv1} [Hz]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to correct this line:

```
# stdv = np.sqrt((np.sum(f - average_frequency )** 2 ) / len(x)) ### NEED TO CHECK
stdv = np.sqrt(np.sum((f - average_frequency)**2) / len(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast! now the standard deviation is 9700 while the mean frequency is 108, so its not possible.
I think it has to do something with the amplitude gain (x_squared), because I defined the frequencies and the spacing between them so what makes the difference to each frequency's 'weight' should be the gain, but I cant point specificly what the algorithm should be.